# How to disabled button after 1 time clicked in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

Hello I have a quiz app that looping multiple choice questions. The choice using button that I loop using `{#each}`.

I was trying to disabled 1 button after a button clicked, but didn't work.

How to disabled a single button after the button clicked in Svelte?

```
let isCorrect
let isAnswered = false
let isDisabled = false

function checkAnswer(correct) {
    isCorrect = correct
    isAnswered = true
    isDisabled = true
    if(isCorrect) {
      addPoint()
    }
  }

let all_answers = [
  {answer: 'Elton John', correct: false},
  {answer: 'Andrew Gold', correct: true}, 
  {answer: 'Leo Sayer', correct: false},  
  {answer: 'Barry White ', correct: false}
]

{#each all_answers as answer}
  <button on:click={() => checkAnswer(answer.correct)}>
    {@html answer.answer} 
  </button>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a reference to the element that was interacted with from the current event.

First, pass the event to the handler:

```html
<button on:click={(e) => checkAnswer(e, answer.correct)}>
```

In the event handler, get a reference to the button element that was clicked on and disable it:

```js
function checkAnswer(e, correct) {
  isCorrect = correct;
  isAnswered = true;
  isDisabled = true;
  if (isCorrect) {
    addPoint();
  }

  // get the button element and disable it
  const node = e.currentTarget;
  node.disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know I can use `e.currentTarget`. This is much simpler only need to disable  `e.currentTarget`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you just want to track whether each of the buttons have been clicked, you could throw an `isClicked` attribute on each object in the `all_answer` list. Then in `checkAnswer` pass the whole object and flip the attribute after the click. Then re-create the `all_answers` array.

This [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6373b34e7f754cc785ae308642307f74?version=3.44.3) does something similar.

```html
<script>
let isCorrect
let isAnswered = false
let isDisabled = false

let total = 0
const addPoint = () => total += 1

function checkAnswer(answer) {
    isCorrect = answer.correct
    isAnswered = true
    answer.isClicked = true;
    if(isCorrect) {
      addPoint()
    }
    all_answers = [...all_answers]
  }

let all_answers = [
  {answer: 'Elton John', correct: false, isClicked: false},
  {answer: 'Andrew Gold', correct: true, isClicked: false}, 
  {answer: 'Leo Sayer', correct: false, isClicked: false},  
  {answer: 'Barry White ', correct: false, isClicked: false}
]

</script>
{#each all_answers as answer}
  <button on:click={() => checkAnswer(answer)} disabled={answer.isClicked}>
    {@html answer.answer} 
  </button>
{/each}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this previously. I understand what I'm  missing now. Now, I can delete `let isDisabled = false` on top